# MYSQL Query : get date which was entered on same name of day

Tags: mysql, database

I have a bunch of data that contain date and some numbers. The table looks like this.

```
ID  |   date                   |   amount  | 
--------------------------------------------
1   |   2017-01-01 00:00:00    |   100     | 
2   |   2017-02-04 00:00:00    |   5       |
3   |   2017-03-11 00:00:00    |   100     |
4   |   2017-04-14 00:00:00    |   20      |
5   |   2017-05-07 00:00:00    |   5       |
```

So let's say today is monday. What I have to do is get data from table which 'date' is monday, same as today. 
I would like to know is there any way do this just using sql query.

Comment: Use your application level code to get the Monday date in ISO format and then query that againt DB. Using any date function on the column when the data is huge will have a severe impact on the performance even if the date column is indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) = DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())
```

use `dayofweek` function

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you column is name col_date You can use  WEEKDAY(col_date) = 0

```
SELECT DISTINCT(col_date) FROM `table` WHERE WEEKDAY(col_date)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from TableName where DAYNAME(`date`)=DAYNAME(CURDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name 
where DAYNAME(`date`) =DAYNAME(CURRENT_DATE);
```